# select specific chars from string

Tags: sql, string, char, h2

I try to select every string before the character `=`

[image]

so I just want 12h and 48h

or 5h , 8h, 12h
etc.

my query:

```
select
activity,
resource
from
(select
trim(both ' ' from regexp_replace (concat(resource_requirement_contingency, ' ;'),'\d{1,5}\D{1,}= - ;', '')) as resource,
activity
FROM PRP_BIA_STAFF_EVALUATION)
```

I tried it with `left()` and `replace()` but it didn't work that way..

Comment: Which sql product are you using?

Comment: im using h2 database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10)
SET @str = '12h=10%'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,0, CHARINDEX('=',@str))
```

Good luck & hope that helps.

Comment: that brings back --> 12h= but the problem is, that the pattern "number+h" occurs more than once in a string so that solution just gives back the first one